# UWP, Access to the path is denied

Tags: c#, file, permissions, uwp

I read some topic about file permission.

Someone said "App can access directories and files which the user manually selected with the FileOpenPicker or FolderPicker"

My codes are like as below:

```
public async void CsvParse()
{
    var picker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();
    picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".csv");
    Windows.Storage.StorageFile file = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();
    if (file != null)
    {
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(file.Path);//this is where app stops working and gives error message.
    }
}
```

Even when I choose file with FilePicker, it still gives me error. But when I choose file from appx folder, it works fine.

Is there a way to access other locations than app's folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it this way:

```
public async void CsvParse()
        {
            var picker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();
            picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".csv");
            Windows.Storage.StorageFile file = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();
            if (file != null)
            {
                IList<string> lines = await FileIO.ReadLinesAsync(file);//this is where app stops working and gives error message.
            }
        }
```

the StorageFile is the way you get access to a file. File.ReadAllLines(file.Path) you are passing a Filename, not the StorageFile but just the filepath is not enough for getting access